# Incorrect Output for Project Euler #2 - Java

Tags: java, fibonacci

## The Word Problem I'm trying to solve:

*Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

            1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

            By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.*

I'm sure you've seen questions about this problem on Project Euler before, but I'm not sure why my solution doesn't work, so I'm hoping you can help!

```
public class Problem2Fibonacci {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
        1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
        By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms. */

    int sum = 0; // This is the running sum
    int num1 = 1; // This is the first number to add
    int num2 = 2; // This is the second number
    int even1 = 0;
    int even2 = 0;
    int evensum = 0;

    while (num2 <= 4000000){ // If i check num2 for the 4000000 cap, num will always be lower

        sum = num1 + num2;  // Add the first 2 numbers to get the 3rd

        if(num2 % 2 == 0){ // if num2 is even
            even1 = num2; // make even1 equal to num2
        }
        if(sum % 2 == 0){ // if sum is even
            even2 = sum; // make even2 equal to sum
        }
        if (even1 != 0  && even2 != 0){ // If even1 and even2 both have values 
        evensum = even1 + even2; // add them together to make the current evensum
        even2 = evensum;
        }
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = sum;
        System.out.println("The current sum is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The current Even sum is: " + evensum);
    }
  }
}
```

So my 2 questions are, 
1. Why doesn't my plan to get sum of even numbers work correctly?
and
2. The last time my loop runs, it uses a num2 that is > 4000000.  Why?

Thanks!

Comment: add the question details and format the question please for better readability

Comment: Hey @Adbelhak can you tell me what I did wrong in my formatting that didn't include my first and last lines?  I just pasted my code in the spot created when you click the Code button.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you :

```
    int first = 0;
    int second = 1;
    int nextInSeq =first+second;
    int sum =0;

    while(nextInSeq < 4000000) {
        first = second;
        second = nextInSeq;
        nextInSeq = first + second;
        if(nextInSeq % 2 ==0)
            sum = sum + nextInSeq;
        System.out.println("Current Sum = " + sum);
    }
    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

For your piece of code : `even1` and `even2` are not required and they are carrying value they hold from previous iterations as you continue.

Comment: and yup this gives you the correct answer..verified ;)

Comment: Hey @nullpointer, thanks for the help!  I'll try to format my question a little better next time.  Any idea where the flaw was in my logic?

Comment: you while condition has `num2<=4000000` and then you evaluate sum = `num1+num2` [what in case the num 2 is 3524578 and num1 is 2178309?] Your sum would exceed by a lot, and then the conditions put in by you using `even1` and `even2` are not appropriate as well as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I see what you're saying, yeah.  During the process of trying to solve this, I first tried to print out the list of fibonacci numbers that were less than 4M, and then I used that engine to move the whole thing forward even when I moved into solving the Even part.  Thanks alot. It's great to have people like you who'll swoop in and help newbs like me out!